# How to login to Sybase ASE using OS credentials?

Tags: linux, sybase, sybase-ase, sybase-ase-15.7

I come from an Oracle background, and I'm used to the concept of OS users that can login to Oracle with DBA privileges in the machine the DB is installed on using their OS credentials as long as the OS user is part of a certain OS group (`oinstall`) using the below syntax:

```
sqlplus / as sysdba
```

In a machine `(Oracle Linux 6.3)` where Sybase ASE `(15.7)` is installed, is there any way I can login the same way as `sa` user?!

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming `sqlplus` is designed to allow password-less DB access under certain scenarios (eg, a custom `perl` script running under the same scenario doesn't, by default, have password-less access to the Oracle DB) ... ?

---

SAP(Sybase) ASE does not come with any applications which, by default, allow for password-less access to the dataserver.

Having said that ... it is possible to setup password-less access, eg:

- design your own custom app that provides password-less access [will likely have to rely on a password file, or an approved method of external authentication]
- configure your environment with one of the approved methods of external authentication [see [ASE Security Admin, External Authentication](https://help.sap.com/viewer/2705a3b1e3df4514ab089cfedf87750d/16.0.3.2/en-US/a926b8dabc2b10148f05924e5890f89d.html) for more details]

Answer (score 1):

Note that the "approved method of external authentication" web page says:

> To use these external authentication methods, you must obtain the ASE_SECDIR security and directory services license package.

So it costs extra money to do something that should be basic like this.  Such is the way that Sybase (er, SAP) does things.